# stop image crawler on mouse hover

Tags: javascript, slider, web-crawler

how can I stop this crawler from dynamicdrive.com on mouse over. I tried some options like:

```
inc: 20, //speed - pixel increment for each iteration of this marquee's movement
mouse: 'cursor driven', //mouseover behavior ('pause' 'cursor driven' or false)
moveatleast: 3,
neutral: 150,
savedirection: true,
random: false,
```

by changing to:

```
inc: 20, //speed - pixel increment for each iteration of this marquee's movement
mouse: 'pause', //mouseover behavior ('pause' 'cursor driven' or false)
moveatleast: 3,
neutral: 150,
savedirection: true,
random: false,
```

but it didn't work.

This crawler goes left when I point my mouse to right of its container but I need it to stop when mouse is over its container.

Here's the link of that page:

http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex2/crawler/index.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try increasing `neutral` to something absurd like `65000`.